# Let $f : R → R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x)f ' (x) < 0$ for all $x ∈ R$. So, $|f(x)|$ is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: derivatives

> Let $f : R → R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(x)f ' (x) <
>  0$ for all $x ∈ R$.
>
> A. $f(x)$ is an increasing function
>
> B. $|f(x)|$ is an increasing function
>
> C. $f(x)$ is a decreasing function
>
> D. $|f(x)|$ is a decreasing function

When $f(x)<0 \Rightarrow  f'(x)>0$
 and when $f(x)>0 \Rightarrow  f'(x)<0$

Then how do we make conclusions about $|f(x)|$?

Comment: Hint: the derivative of $f(x)^2$ is $2f(x)f'(x)$.

Comment: Hint: $\;\left(f^2(x)\right)' = 2 f(x)f'(x) \lt 0\,$, so $f^2(x) = |f(x)|^2$ is $\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D, there are 2 possibilities. Either f(x) is positive and f'(x) is negative, or f(x) is negative and f'(x) is positive. For the first case imagine a downward slope above the x-axis. For the second case imagine an upward slope below the x-axis. If you put absolute value, first case wouldn't change since f(x) is positive. For the second case, it would be inverted to above the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$g(x)=ln |f(x)|$$ then 
$$g^{\prime}(x)<0$$ by assumption and so $g(x)$ is decreasing. This implies that $|f(x)|$ is decreasing.